# Show TYPO3 content only during working hours by recurrently publish and unpublish content every working day

Tags: typo3, scheduler, typo3-10.x

I want to display a TYPO3 content element every Monday till Friday between 9am and 5pm. With the default options I am only able to add a single publish and a single expire date and time.

How could I mange this in TYPO3 v10 (on the server side without using JavaScript)?

I found an extension ([Content Scheduler](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/cw_content_scheduler)), that can manage recurring publishing and unpublishing dates but it's not possible to define s.th. like 'every working day'.

I was thinking about using the TYPO3 scheduler (or native cron job) calling a CLI command but TYPO3 does not offer a command to publish and unpublish content elements.

Any ideas? Maybe using the good old TypoScript?

Comment: You can use a custom CLI command which just sets the starttime and endtime of the content element to your needs (I assume it is always the same one).
Depending on the content, a custom plugin can also be used. Then you have to take care obout the caching and clear the cache programmatically.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your fast reply. I know that it is possible to write a custom extension or CLI command but I tough that someone might have ready to use code snippets or knows about an extension because this requirement seems not that unusual to me.

Answer (score 1):

All visibility timings of records is not periodical but on fixed dates (and times) for starting and/or ending of visibility.

The only option I know where you can ignore parts of the full timestamp are **conditions in TypoScript**.
The condition for TYPO3 10 is described in [this manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/10.4/en-us/Conditions/Index.html#date)

this will result in a typoscript like this:

```
[date("G") > 8 && date("G") < 17]
page.10.variables.content < styles.content.get

[else]
page.10.variables.content = TEXT
page.10.variables.content.value = Sorry. we are closed.<br />Please come back at 9:00.
[global]
```

Of course this will not consider the weekend and you need to enhance it.
Note that you can't stack conditions into each other!

```
[date('N') > 5]
// just saturday and sunday:
page.10.variables.content = TEXT
page.10.variables.content.value = Sorry. we are closed.<br />Please come back on Monday at 9:00

[date('N') == 5 && date('G') > 16]
// friday in the evening
page.10.variables.content = TEXT
page.10.variables.content.value = Sorry. we are closed.<br />Please come back on Monday at 9:00


[date("G") > 8 && date("G") < 17]
page.10.variables.content < styles.content.get

[else]
page.10.variables.content = TEXT
page.10.variables.content.value = Sorry. we are closed.<br />Please come back at 9:00
[global]
```

---

You also can compute these **conditions in FLUID**. Either with apropiate variables you provide (for dayOfWeek and hour)
or with a matching viewhelper:

---

If you want to use **PHP** to provide different content at different times in the week you can do it with:

- your own userFunction for your own condition
- or your own ViewHelper
- or an controller for special content which handles it internally

Comment: Thanks @bernd-wilke-πφ but this is all about a "hardcoded" content in the template that will be visible and hidden scheduled. I want to hide and display a standard content element that an editor is able to modify and position freely among the other content elements. Only the uid must be known.
What do you mean by "*a controller for special content which handles it internally*"?

Comment: A controller (or plugin) can build it's own logic which data to display when (note the need for proper hashing)